# Files not loading in different directories

Tags: html, css, file

I work on several sites for clients so i have create a virtual-host with a directory structure like this

```
http://clients/site3/
```

I am workin in this directory right now

```
http://clients/site3/logged/index.php
```

I have a common `header.php` file that i include to all files which contain links to some files that need to be included in all files. for ex a css

Now i am having issue pointing to files like loading css..
This is a link in `header.php` file

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='css/loadBar.css' />
css/ folder is in logged directory
```

But when i work in `user/` directory which is in `logged/` directory

Then its not able to load that css

If i point css file like `http://clients/site3/logged/css/loadBar.css` then i will have issue when i will upload this file to server on www.example.com/

if i point css file like this

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='./css/loadBar.css' />
```

So it work as far as i am in `logged/` directory but when i navigate to `user/`directory which is inside `logged/` directory than it does not work because it try to load file from current directory(`user/`)

and to test files on server i am using same directory structure for now.

```
http://example.com/site3/
```

For Now i have created a separate `VirtualHost` name site3 and i am accessing it like http://site3/ and pointing files like this

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='/logged/css/loadBar.css' />
//The forward slash points to root directory of domain
```

I am using Rewrite Rule for allowing files to open it withou .php extension I think that might be causing problems

Here is the Rewrite Rule

```
RewriteEngine On ###### Turns rewrite engine on not need to turn it on again
#5 -- Allow URLs to open without .php extension -- ###
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1\.php
```

Comment: is the css shared across all clients and sites?

Comment: No that is a common css for `site3` directory to included in all files.

Comment: Hmm, not sure how you could do this in a way where one path will be valid on local, test server and real server. Do you have a build process that could change the paths depending on which environment you're building for? I have a `gulp` task in one of my projects which changes relative paths for css into absolute paths instead.

Comment: What happens if you add `./` infront?
e.g. `href='./css/loadBar.css'`

Comment: Where is your CSS folder? In the logged folder or in the site3 folder?

Comment: css folder is inside logged/ directory which is inside root directory of site3
. I have also update question @yann

Comment: @chris i have updated question more details

Comment: I'd suggest you putting in comment the rewrite rules to see if that is the problem. (I don't think but it's worth checking it out) If it still doesn't work, i'd try, One good solution would be to write the full adress to see if it works: for example http://localhost/myTestProject/css/style.css